# Swift 2: open and save a text document

Tags: swift, sample

I am a seasoned developer, but new to Swift.

Is there a simple code sample to open a text file using a file picker, and savie it? I have seen some examples, but they are either for an older version of Swift (and don’t work any more) or seek to do something more complex. The books I have bought focus on the language itself.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link to that outdated example that does not work anymore? It's probably possible to update it for current Swift.

Comment: One example I have seen in particular acknowledges the issue, but states they don’t have time to update it. Unfortunately.

Comment: I created a playground called [SwiftFiles](https://github.com/sketchytech/SwiftFiles) that demonstrates Save, Load, Move, Delete, etc.